# Make curl call to grpc service

Tags: kotlin, grpc

I'm trying to learn grpc using kotlin and make a simple grpc service with following proto definition :

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "br.bortoti";
option java_outer_classname = "StockProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package br.bortoti;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service StockService {
  rpc GetStock (GetStockRequest) returns (Stock) {
    option(google.api.http) = {
      get: "V1/stocks/{stock}"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}

message Stock {
  string ticker = 1;
}

message GetStockRequest {
  string ticker = 1;
}

message GetStockReply {
  string ticker = 1;
}
```

so, i'm basically mapping a service to a get request.

but when i try to call this url from curl like :

```
curl http://localhost:8088/V1/stocks/1
```

i get the error :
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

and from the server side i have :

```
INFO: Transport failed
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: GET /V1/stocks/1
```

how can i make the server accept http 1.1 calls? is it even possible?

Comment: gRPC is based on HTTP/2 and has its own [protocol specification](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md). So a normal `curl` call won't be accepted by the gRPC server. There are a lot of command line tools work similar to `curl` for gRPC, some widely used ones are [grpc_cli](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md) and [bloomrpc](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc).

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is two question.

The gRPC use HTTP2 and need lots of headers so it is diffcult request by curl. Maybe you need [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl)

And the path `V1/stocks/{stock}` need use grpc-gateway toghter, you can reference [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) for more detail.

Since you are learn how to use gRPC, maybe you can reference this project: [helloworlde/grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample), feel free to translate chinese.